# How to check, when/whether a quadratic equation has iteger roots

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratics

I am familliar with the Jacobi symbol and thus can check for an equation, whether it has solutions in a given $\mathbb{Z}_n$. But how do I check for integer solutions in general?

In perticular, I found the question: for which $a$ does $ax^2+2x+4=0$ have integer solutions?

Answer (score 2):

We interpret the question as asking for which **integers** $a$ does the equation have at least one integer solution. Of course there is $a=0$. Now look for non-zero $a$.

By the Rational Roots Theorem, any rational solution is of the form $\frac{p}{q}$, where $p$ divides $4$ and $q$ divides $a$. If this is to be an integer, it must be $\pm 1$, $\pm 2$, or $\pm 4$. Check for each of these whether it yields an integer value of $a$.

Comment: @OP Note that RRT requires that $\,p/q\,$ is in *lowest terms*, i.e. $\,\gcd(p,q)=1.\,$ But, of course, we can, wlog, assume that, since every fraction can be reduced to one in lowest terms by canceling any common divisor. This is worth emphasizing because that requirement is often overlooked, which can lead to errors.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** think of the quadratic formula and the $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$ in it.

Answer (score 0):

You know that the answer to that is $x=\frac{-2 \pm \sqrt{4-16a}}{2a}=\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1-4a}}{a}$.

You have a condition for those solutions to be real ($1-4a\geq0$), then you need to ensure that it's a perfect square which is $\equiv 1[a]$ or$\equiv -1[a]$ .

For $\equiv 1[a]$, solutions are in the form $a=-\frac{4+2k}{k^2}$, $k\in \mathbb{Z}^*$

Comment: I understand, that $a\leq 0$ but how exactly can I find the $a$s, for which $1-4a$ is a square?

Comment: you write what you want, that is: $1-4a=u^2$ Then you reinject in the equation which gives you $\frac{-1+u}{a}$, and as such you need $-1+u = ka$ to have an integer. You then reinject this value of $u$ above.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\,\ a,x,p\in\Bbb Z,\,\ p\,$ prime, $\,ax^2\!+px+p^2=0\,\Rightarrow\, x\mid p^2\,\Rightarrow\,x = \pm p^n,\ n\le 2.\,$ Therefore

$$ a \,=\, \dfrac{-p^2-px}{x^2} \,=\, \dfrac{-p^2\pm p^{n+1}}{p^{2n}} \,=\, \dfrac{-p^{2-n}\pm p}{p^n}\in\Bbb Z\iff  n<2 \iff n = 0,1$$

**Remark** $\ $ That the factors of $\,p^2$ have said form follows from *uniqueness* of prime factorizations. In your special case $\,p = 2\,$ so we don't need  such a powerful result. But generally we will.